# List<Map<String, Object>> variable as a response for front end

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax, post

I have a variable

```
List<Map<String, Object>> arrayOfRoomRowsForAllRooms = selectEntireRoomTableFromDB();
```

The list contains multiple records from my database. The content of the variable looks like this:

**[{room_id=2, fee_amount=300, room_location=east, room_type=1, room_status=false}, {room_id=3, fee_amount=350, room_location=north, room_type=1, room_status=false}]**

My issue right now is that the *arrayOfRoomRowsForAllRooms* list is initiated in a middle tier servlet. I need to pass it to the front end via XMLHttpRequest() response.

I have been using the code below to pass JSONArrays to the front end

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(JSONArrayVariable.toString());
```

What is the best way to pass this variable to the front end? Should I be trying to convert *arrayOfRoomRowsForAllRooms* to JSON? and how will I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use libraries like Jackson or Gson to parse your arrayOfRoomRowsForAllRooms. Here is a nice tutorial on how to use Jackson https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial. Jackson is used by frameworks like Spring boot to transparently serialize your response object to json.

Comment: Thank you, that did it for me